# Mocking a generic method with type constraints

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method I want to test in a class:

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
  public T SetProperty<T>(string value, T object) where T : AnObjectType, IAnotherObjectType
  {
    object.property = value;
    return object;
  }
}
```

I'm using a mock object type that also implements IAnotherObjectTypelike this:

```
class MockObjectType: AnObjectType, IAnotherObjectType
{
  (implementation of IAnotherObjectType)
}
```

I want to set up a mock for my class, and CallBase for the method I'm testing, using my mock object, something like this:

```
string value = "value";
MockObjectType mockObject = new MockObjectType();

Mock<ClassUnderTest> mockClassUnderTest= new Mock<ClassUnderTest>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mockClassUnderTest.Setup(foo => foo.SetProperty<It.IsSubtype<IAnotherObjectType>>(
    It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<It.IsSubtype<IAnotherObjectType>>()))
  .CallBase();

var result = mockClassUnderTest.Object.SetProperty(value, mockObject);

Assert.That(result.property, Is.EqualTo(value));
```

But this code won't compile, showing the error:

> The type '`Moq.It.IsSubtype<IAnotherObjectType>`' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method '`SetProperty<T>(string, T)`'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '`Moq.It.IsSubtype<IAnotherObjectType>`' to '`AnObjectType`'

What am I doing wrong here? I assume this is an issue with the syntax of some kind, so how should I express what I'm trying to do here?

**EDIT**
I've clarified the relationship between the object types that the constraints specify.

I should also clarify that the test I've described is a simplified one. I also want to verify other behaviours of the method, i.e. calling other mocked methods, etc. Using a mock of the class under test is required for this verification. I just want to know how to CallBase for this method on the mocked class.

Comment: Is ObjectType: IObjectType (Implementing IObjectType) ?

Comment: What you want to test, behaviour of method SetProperty()?

Comment: Yes, I want to test that SetProperty does set the property.

Comment: Then why are you setting behaviour of the same method that you want to test?

Comment: I'm not, I'm using the CallBase property. My understanding is that I need to specify the parameters in order to do this.

Comment: If you want to verify SetProperty behaviour it could be done without so much mocking. Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: @Clint No, ObjectType does not implement IObjectType

Comment: @aforest-ccc, not sure if you are doing justice by mocking it this way, something seems to be off.
By the way try replacing CallBase with .CallBack(()=>{//Body of callback});

Answer (score 1):

Do not mock the subject under test. Mock the dependency to behave as expected when the test is exercised

```
//Arrange
string value = "value";
var mockObject = new Mock<AnObjectType>();
mockObject.As<IAnotherObjectType>().SetupAllProperties();
// now the mock also implements IAnotherObjectType
mockObject.SetupAllProperties();


ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();

//Act
var result = classUnderTest.SetProperty(value, mockObject.Object);

//Assert
Assert.That(result.property, Is.EqualTo(value));
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: @aforest-ccc Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the *actual* problem.

Comment: I've described what I want to do: CallBase for the method on the mocked class.
I've described the problem I'm having: I can't work out the syntax to do that.
I have provided as little code as possible to produce the issue I'm having, and demonstrate the syntax I've tried.

Comment: @aforest-ccc based on the shown code the subject under test is not mockable and should not be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

It could be tested without mocking the actual method under the test

```
    public void SetPropertySetsValue()
    {
        string value = "value";
        MockObjectType mockObject = new MockObjectType(); // or create object of ObjectType
        ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();


        var result = classUnderTest.SetProperty(value, mockObject);
        Assert.AreEqual(value, mockObject.property);
    }
```

That would verify the value was set by SetProperty() method correctly or not.

Comment: I'm not mocking the method, I'm using a mock of the class under test, and using CallBase to call the method in the original class. Using a mock of the class under test means I can specify MockBehavior.Strict, and verify if it calls other methods, etc.

Comment: In a single test you should be testing one behaviour only i.e. if it assigns value?, for testing other behaviour of same method you should write another test. And if implementation is correct, you need to mock external dependencies only and not the actual class under test.

Comment: @aforest-ccc Are there any compile time errors when you remove .CallBase() from your code ?